# PySpark - Truncate Groups Time Series to just 24 Hours

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 200,000,000 rows of tags (grouped by one level up) with time series data. An example of the data:

```
Tag   Group  Timestamp           Value
Tag_1 Engine 2021-08-09 01:01:04 0
Tag_1 Engine 2021-08-09 01:01:08 1
Tag_1 Engine 2021-08-09 01:01:12 2
Tag_2 Engine 2021-02-01 04:01:04 0
Tag_2 Engine 2021-02-01 04:01:08 1
Tag_2 Engine 2021-02-01 04:01:12 2
Tag_3 Engine 2021-04-20 01:04:44 0
Tag_3 Engine 2021-04-20 01:04:48 1
Tag_3 Engine 2021-04-20 01:04:52 2
Tag_1 Propeller 2021-01-21 01:05:52  0
...
Tag_3 Propeller 2021-01-01 01:05:58  2
```

This data is very large. How do I filter each of the `Group's Tags` so that I only have the last 24-hours of non-null data to analyze?

To clarify, for each of the tags I only want the last 24 hours of non-null data not the entire history.

So far I think the solution looks like:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("Tag").orderBy(F.col("Timestamp").cast('long')).last(-25*24, 0)

#Using -25*24 for 25*24 timestamp in the past with an assumed frequency of 4 min timestamps.

df = df.over(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently:

- Order operations are n*log(n) in the best case. If your set is already ordered it could be O(n^2) depending on the algorithm used.
- Grouping needs at least O(n) plus memory.

My bet would be:

- Grab a random sample and take a look at the label distribution to spot for hot keys and get to know how big is the dragon we are fighting .
- Filter the dataset, thus reducing the amount of data to process. That's a one pass of the dataset (would be a full table scan in a database) with complexity O(n). You can speed up this step if you preprocess the data exporting the dataset to a columnar format like parquet.
- After filtering, do the group by operation (if you need it later), or just sort by the tag you need.